# IBM Worklight connection to HttpAdapter is getting reset

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

In my app I'm invoking a Http Adapter procedure for certain action to perform. The procedure does not work every time on invocation. Sometimes its connection to Server gets reset & sometimes gives perfect response. Someone please tell me what may be the reason for this and how to handle this one ?

Here is the Exception i'm getting in Worklight console,

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project TestApp]User_Profile/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project TestApp]{
   "arr": [
      {
         "body": {
            "content": "[{\"Text\":\"User\",\"Value\":\"08\/31\/2013 17:03:37\"},{\"Text\":\"SampleName\",\"Value\":\"08\/31\/2013 17:03:37\"},{\"Text\":\"James\",\"Value\":\"08\/31\/2013 17:03:37\"},{\"Text\":\"Anderson\",\"Value\":\"08\/31\/2013 17:03:37\"}]",
            "contentType": "application\/json"
         },
         "method": "post",
         "path": "\/UserInfo.svc\/GetUserDetails",
         "returnedContentType": "application\/json"
      }
   ]
}
Http request failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project TestApp]java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is solved but found the similar question and some suggestions here: [IBM Worklight 6.0 - Socket Exception connection reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628339/ibm-worklight-6-0-socket-exception-connection-reset).

It says like this:
According to the exception, the root cause is that the connection was reset. There are several reasons why this could happen, one being network packets being lost or similar lower level connectivity issues; another possible reason could be that SharePoint is timing out the socket to free resources.

The best way to troubleshoot this kind of problems IMO is by sniffing into the network connection using tools like WireShark or Fiddler

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate on what that thread recommends, should that link ever break in the future.