# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Socket Exception connection reset

Tags: sockets, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on a worklight project, in it I am consuming web services that are hosted on SharePoint server using a Worklight Adapter.

Some times I am getting a `Socket Exception` and the adapter fails to call the web service.
This happening randomly.

From the development server log:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure.

Http request failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project TestApp]java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
```

Comment: @Idan Adar , this problem is not solved till now why this is happening randomly. I am using worklight 6.1 and going through the same problem. At the same time socket expection is coming and same time it is getting data from adapter.

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception, the root cause is that the connection was reset. There are several reasons why this could happen, one being network packets being lost or similar lower level connectivity issues; another possible reason could be that SharePoint is timing out the socket to free resources.

The best way to troubleshoot this kind of problems IMO is by sniffing into the network connection using tools like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)

Please have a look at the top-voted answer and comments to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585599/whats-causing-my-java-net-socketexception-connection-reset) for more insights into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this same issue when connecting to an HTTP server in front of IBM Commerce.  The solution so far for us has been to put the Worklight server and IIS HTTP server on two different subnets.  We are investigating why this the case.  Not sure if 100% related to what you are seeing but figured I would answer here.